# "+ Show All Sites" text button doesn't do anything

Tags: bug

I was browsing https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/advertising/why-stack-overflow and scrolled almost to the bottom and clicked `+ Show All Sites` toggle which apparently doesn't work:

[image: a gif of how it does nothing]

Tried this in latest versions of Firefox and Opera.